# Format text in a link in reStructuredText

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

How do you format text within a denoted link in reStructuredText?

Specifically, I wish to generate the following HTML from my rst:

```
<a href="http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html"><tt>optparse.OptionParser</tt> documentation documentation</a>
```

The result should look like this:

> [`optparse.OptionParser`
>   documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html)

where the "optparse.OptionParser" portion is in fixed-width font.

I tried

````
```optparse.OptionParser`` <http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html>`_
````

however, this gave

```
<tt class="docutils literal">`optparse.OptionParser</tt> documentation &lt;<a class="reference external" href="http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html">http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html</a>&gt;`_
```

which looks like this

> ``optparse.OptionParser
>   `documentation
>   <http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html>\`_

Answer (score 107, accepted):

This construct:

```
Here you have |optparse.OptionParser|_.

.. |optparse.OptionParser| replace:: ``optparse.OptionParser`` documentation
.. _optparse.OptionParser: http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html
```

produces this HTML (some linebreaks added):

```
<p>Here you have 
  <a class="reference external" href="http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html">
  <tt class="docutils literal"><span class="pre">optparse.OptionParser</span></tt> documentation</a>.
</p>
```

I realize that this is not *exactly* what you asked for, but maybe it's close enough. See also http://docutils.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#is-nested-inline-markup-possible.

Comment: This is really beautiful. I was looking at all kinds of over-engineered solutions, including writing custom extensions before I found this.

Comment: **This is _not_ really beautiful.** This is horrible. All sane markup languages support indefinite nesting of inline markup, because this is 2016. Context-free parsing has been trivially solved since 1959. (_Chomsky: ["On certain formal properties of grammars."](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019995859903626#)_) The inability of the reStructuredText parser to perform genuine context-free parsing is a crass, ugly blemish on an otherwise sterling facade. The well-defined and highly extensible syntax of reST deserves better. (_Someone should feel bad about this._)

Comment: The ["details here" link](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/dev/rst/alternatives.html#nested-inline-markup) in that FAQ entry is interesting… especially “other forms of inline markup may be nested if unambiguous”; I wonder if the only way it's going to happen is if someone just takes a stab at making a patch set that handles the unambiguous cases and then this ["slightly out-of-spec" flavor of RST becomes commonplace](https://www.gwern.net/Bitcoin-is-Worse-is-Better) enough that everything just snowballs from there(or if not at least we get good support for the unambiguous cases right away)

Comment: be advised this only works for hyperlinks and not for intra-document links (like `:ref:`)

Comment: Apparently here we are, ten years later, and this workaround is still required.

Comment: “Indefinite nesting of inline markup” is WYSIWYG formatting nightmare fuel. MS Word has that. Enforcing some limits is reasonable IMO, considering one can always extend RST like Sphinx does.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried [intersphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/intersphinx.html)? Using that extension, the following markup:

```
:py:class:`optparse.OptionParser`
```

produces this HTML:

```
<a class="reference external" href="http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/optparse.html#optparse.OptionParser" title="(in Python v2.6)"><tt class="xref py py-class docutils literal"><span class="pre">optparse.OptionParser</span></tt></a>
```

Tested with Python 2.6 and Sphinx 1.0.5.

Comment: Ah, well, I didn't know about intersphinx. Thanks, it's good to know. The link to `optparse` is actually just an example. I'm concerned with formatting text in a link to any URI, really.

Answer (score 5):

Taking from the same FAQ page referenced by mzjn:

```
The "raw" directive can be used to insert raw HTML into HTML output:

Here is some |stuff|.

.. |stuff| raw:: html

   <em>emphasized text containing a
   <a href="http://example.org">hyperlink</a> and
   <tt>inline literals</tt></em>
```

It should in theory be possible to do complicated things with that that can't be done with RST.

Comment: this works, but it also breaks other writers (LaTeX, PDF, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to essentially do get HTML/CSS equivalent of

```
<span class="red">This is red text</span>
```

in reStructuredText using Sphinx, you can do this by creating a role:

```
.. role:: red
```

Then you use it like this:

```
:red:`This is red text`
```

There should be only one tick mark `` ` `` at the end of the line above.
You, of course, have to have

```
.red { color: red }
```

in your CSS file.