# Insert a link into bold text in reStructuredText

Tags: restructuredtext, docutils

I try to insert a link into bold text in reStructuredText but failed.

This is my rst source:

```
**Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, `consectetur <http://www.example.com>`_ 
adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore 
magna aliqua.**
```

but I got:

```
<strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, `consectetur <http://www.example.com>`_ 
adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
magna aliqua.</strong>
```

I want to get this:

```
<strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="http://www.example.com">consectetur</a> 
adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
magna aliqua.</strong>
```

Comment: This question was answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743845/format-text-in-a-link-in-restructuredtext

Answer (score 23, accepted):

At the moment it seems that this is not possible: see the Docutils FAQ, specifically the question ["Is nested inline markup possible"](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#is-nested-inline-markup-possible). The answer basically states that nested inline markup is on the to do list, so it will eventually be possible to do what you ask in the question, and provides a couple of work arounds (which they state are not recommended).

Since the workarounds are not recommended perhaps for the time being you could just do something like:

```
**Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,** `consectetur <http://www.example.com>`_ 
**adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore 
magna aliqua.**
```

Of course your link would not be bold, but at least it will be a valid link.

Answer (score 6):

Not exactly the HTML you ask for, but it creates a link inside of a fully bold text:

```
.. _consectetur: http://www.example.com
.. |consectetur| replace:: **consectetur** 

**Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,** |consectetur|_
**dolor elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.**
```

will produce:

```
<strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</strong>
<a href="http://www.example.com"><strong>consectetur</strong></a>
<strong>dolor elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</strong>
```

Comment: Whoa, thank you! For my purpose, this works _beautifully_!

Answer (score 3):

One further workaround would be to mark the whole paragraph as bold, if applicable.

```
.. class:: bold

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, `consectetur <http://www.example.com>`_ 
adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore 
magna aliqua.
```

Comment: does not seem to work: https://gist.github.com/carbolymer/e8e2f5351aa7c0bf8c2130db72cc5e3b

Answer (score 0):

I've made a Shpinx extension [xxlink.py](https://github.com/Un1Gfn/beaglebone/blob/bdd2e8a888d6b1db468eddaf745ed84396a57cd0/Documentation/extension/xxlink.py)
which registers Docutils roles `:stlink:` and `:emlink:`.

reST

```
`example <https://example.org>`__
:stlink:`example <https://example.org>`
:emlink:`example <https://example.org>`
```

emited HTML

```
<p><a class="reference external" href="https://example.org">example</a>
<strong><a class="reference external" href="https://example.org">example</a></strong>
<em><a class="reference external" href="https://example.org">example</a></em></p>
```

result

[example](https://example.org) [**example**](https://example.org) [*example*](https://example.org)

Now I don't have to define 2 extra text substitutions for every single em/strong link.

*Suggestions are welcome.*

Comment: The GitHub link does not work.