# How do I mark text fixed width and bold in Sphinx / reStructured Text?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm working on generating documentation with Sphinx / reStructured Text.  I can mark text either **bold** or as `fixed width`.  How do I mark text with both formats like this: **`--bold-and-fixed-width`** ?

Comment: Does `**``fixed width``**` not work? It seems to [with pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/try/?text=**%60%60fixed+width%60%60**&from=rst&to=html).

Comment: I'm using version 1.1.3, and `\ **``fixed width``**\ ` produces bold text including the back tick chars.

Comment: I've found an only render tool that demonstrates that it doesn't work [link](http://rst.ninjs.org/?n=78b0e4c7e131fc33047f5956599e30af&theme=basic)

Comment: It seems that nested inline markup is not possible, see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9645684/623518).