# How to make verbatim text inside a link in Restructured Text?

Tags: restructuredtext, docutils

How can I make verbatim text inside a link in Restructured Text?

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

[`example`](http://example.com)

I tried the following

````
```example`` <http://example.com>`__
` ``example`` <http://example.com>`__
````

but both cases are rendered as

```
` example <http://example.com>`__
```

Comment: How about this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4836544/407651

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>As far as I know and can find in the documentation you simply can't do this.</strike>

<strike>The same goes for trying to make a link bold or italic (which is what I was looking for).</strike>

Apparently it **is** possible (see the comment from @jJason S) below pointing to [Format text in a link in reStructuredText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743845/format-text-in-a-link-in-restructuredtext/4836544#4836544)

Comment: you can -- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743845/format-text-in-a-link-in-restructuredtext/4836544#4836544