# How do you hyperlink monospaced text in reStructuredText?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

```
`pandoc <https://github.com/jgm/pandoc>`_
```

creates a link that looks like

[pandoc](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc)

But how do I create a link to monospaced text: [`pandoc`](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc)

If I try

```
` ``pandoc`` <https://github.com/jgm/pandoc>`_
```

I get this crud:

` `pandoc` <https://github.com/jgm/pandoc>`_

Comment: It is a bit cumbersome, but it can be done: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4836544/407651