# Substitutions inside Sphinx code blocks aren't replaced

Tags: python, python-sphinx, substitution, restructuredtext

In this reST example meant to be rendered by Sphinx, |yaco_url| doesn't get replaced because it's in a code-block:

```
.. |yaco_url| replace:: http://yaco.es/

You can use wget to download it:

.. code-block:: console

    $ wget |yaco_url|package.tar.gz
```

I  wonder if there is some way to force the replacement of |yaco_url| before rendering the code block.

Comment: This question is almost the same but doesn't work inside code blocks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227037/substitutions-inside-links-in-rest-sphinx

Comment: Hey - did you find an answer to this?

Comment: No, I didn't. In the end I had to replace all |yaco_url| with a sed command.

Comment: If you haven't found it already, you might find the programoutput extension handy: http://packages.python.org/sphinxcontrib-programoutput/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the "parsed-literal" directive.

```
.. parsed-literal::

    ./home/user/somecommand-|version|
```

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/sphinx-dev/ABzaUiCfO_8:

Comment: This is close to my needs, though I'm still struggling with then treating the result as a code block, for proper formatting.

Comment: @HowardM.LewisShip I'm struggling with the same issue. did you find a solution?

Comment: No, I never did.

Answer (score 7):

Found a better solution (in my opinion), that can be used in others directives like `:samp:` and might be useful for future readers.

config.py:

```
def ultimateReplace(app, docname, source):
    result = source[0]
    for key in app.config.ultimate_replacements:
        result = result.replace(key, app.config.ultimate_replacements[key])
    source[0] = result

ultimate_replacements = {
    "{TEST}" : "replaced"
}

def setup(app):
   app.add_config_value('ultimate_replacements', {}, True)
   app.connect('source-read', ultimateReplace)
```

And this kind of markup:

```
.. http:get:: testing/replacement/{TEST}
```

Properly generates like:

```
testing/replacement/replaced
```

Note, that if using this to replace an argument in the `:samp:` directive, a double bracket `{` is require.

```
:samp:`func({{TEST}})`.
```

source: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/4054

Comment: Nice! This worked well rather than the accepted answer as I still wasn't able to do a replace in a code block where I needed formatting.

Comment: This works great in `code-block`, but I discovered that it will not work where the `code-block` is within an `include`. However it appears that Sphinx 7.2.5 added a new event [`include-read`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/appapi.html#event-include-read) that might handle this situation. Alas, we're stuck on an older version for now.