# Can I substitute in a reStructuredText code-block?

Tags: substitution, restructuredtext

Is there a way to do a replacement or variable substitution with `replace` in reStructuredText inside of a `code-block`?

For example, in

```
.. code-block:: sh

    $ |script| args moreargs
    Some output

    $ another_script args moreargs
    Some more output
```

using

```
.. |script| replace:: some_script
```

displays as

```
$ |script| args moreargs
Some output

$ another_script args moreargs
Some more output
```

and not

```
$ some_script args moreargs
Some output

$ another_script args moreargs
Some more output
```

I know that I can use [`parsed-literal`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12644533/656912), but that looses syntax coloring.

Comment: I think the answer is no. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/27185467/407651, http://stackoverflow.com/q/27392934/407651.

Comment: @mzjn: It looks like that will be an answer.