# How do I output a config value in a Sphinx .rst file?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I've got the following in `conf.py`:

```
def setup(app):
    app.add_config_value('base_url','http://localhost:2000', True)
```

How do I get this into my .rst files? I wrote this:

```
:base_url:/my_app/api/application/
```

But it only prints `:base_url:` instead of the actual URL.

How do I get the actual config value to be emitted?

Comment: So for the moment we did something very kludgy. We have a script that simply does a find -exec sed over the generated documents, changing the URLs in question. So it works, but...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Substitutions inside links in reST / Sphinx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227037/substitutions-inside-links-in-rest-sphinx)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For the substitution of links **extlinks** is fine, for including arbitrary config values as asked in your question you can use [rst_epilog](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-rst_epilog) for substitutions (or [rst_prolog](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-rst_prolog) for text, that should be added on top of your .rst files):

In your conf.py:

```
my_config_value = 42
rst_epilog = '.. |my_conf_val| replace:: %d' % my_config_value
```

In your .rst source:

> My config value is |my_conf_val|!

In your output:

> My config value is 42!

Comment: Ok thanks, this has possibilities. One issue I've noticed with the extlinks is that I can't use it in the middle of a code block. It then just outputs ":api_url:" instead of the substitution. Would **rst_epilog** handle that better?

Comment: I just tried it, but it doesn't work in code blocks. Maybe this is a bug in docutils, as sphinx relies on docutils substitutions here (and I think extlinks to).

Comment: I'll keep hacking it. Thanks for the answer. It's more general than mine so you get the vote.

Comment: `%s` would probably be a better example, since it is more general and fits the question asked.

Answer (score 3):

Ah hah!

Take a look at the [**sphinx.ext.extlinks**](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/extlinks.html) module.

So I have code in my conf.py that does this:

```
extlinks = {'api_url' : (settings.BASE_URL + '%s', settings.BASE_URL)}
```

And in my .rst file, I have this:

```
:api_url:`/myapp/api/application/`
```

which produces the nicely formatted link as such:

```
http://localhost:8000/myapp/api/application/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert any **conf.py** existing variable (just with version is working) in any **.rst** file:

conf.py:

```
version = "0.0.1"
```

rst file text:

```
Version: |version|
```

result:

[image]

EDIT: As @zakariya said, this is only working with version, no other variables.

Comment: This approach works only with `version`. It does not work with custom variables or other sphinx-defined variables  (e.g. author, copyright, project).