# Sphinx docs variable

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm writing documentation for a new project using `Sphinx`

But because this project is new, its name may change and I don't want to replace all reference of "Project Name" in all my documentation.

So I want to know if there is a way to put some variable/constant on `Sphinx` to do that.

I know there is a `i18n` feature on `Sphinx`, so I can use gettext to change the "Project Name" without something else. But I'm looking for a proper way to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I output a config value in a Sphinx .rst file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030149/how-do-i-output-a-config-value-in-a-sphinx-rst-file)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The project name is referenced by `sphinx` using a configuration value. The name of your project is asked if you use `sphinx-quickstart` to create xyour `sphinx` project.
You can change the project name afterward by changing `project` in your `conf.py`

You can use config values in your `.rst` files by defining them in `conf.py` with `rst_epilog` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10042061/1301710) for an example).

Comment: So in practice place this in your conf.py: `rst_epilog = '.. |project_name| replace:: %s' % project`. Then in your .rst you can simply use `|project_name|` anywhere in the text.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you override the value of `project` through `sphinx-build`'s `-D` command-line option, the substitution is not automatically updated.

Answer (score 7):

From the [Sphinx documentation](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/2.0/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#substitutions):

> reST supports “substitutions” ([ref](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#substitution-definitions)), which are pieces of text and/or markup referred to in the text by `|name|`. They are defined like footnotes with explicit markup blocks, like this:
>
> ```
> .. |name| replace:: replacement *text*
> ```
>
> or this:
>
> ```
> .. |caution| image:: warning.png
>          :alt: Warning!
> ```
>
> See the [reST reference for substitutions](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#substitution-definitions) for details.
>
> If you want to use some substitutions for all documents, put them into [`rst_prolog`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/2.0/usage/configuration.html#confval-rst_prolog) or [`rst_epilog`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/2.0/usage/configuration.html#confval-rst_epilog) or put them into a separate file and include it into all documents you want to use them in, using the `include` directive. (Be sure to give the include file a file name extension differing from that of other source files, to avoid Sphinx finding it as a standalone document.)

Add your "project variable" in `rst_prolog` and use substitution.