# Let sphinx use version from setup.py

Tags: python, package, python-sphinx

If I do `sphinx-quickstart` I get asked about the version of the project.

I want to avoid to have two places for the version of my project.

How to do this in the python packing world?

Comment: So, did it any of the answers work for you? If so, please accept the respective answer. If not, what's the issue?

Comment: Thank you for asking. I am not in a hurry with this topic. I want a canonical answer. I will ask on dist-sig: https://www.python.org/community/sigs/current/distutils-sig

Comment: @guetti's link to the "single sourcing the package version" section of the Python packaging docs seems to be broken - current link is https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/single-sourcing-package-version/

Answer (score 32):

The easiest (and probably cleanest) way is to define [`__version__`](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0396/) for the `__init__.py` of your top-level package, and then import that package and read the version in both `setup.py` and your Sphinx project's `conf.py`.

So lets say your project is called `myproject`.

Move your current version out of `setup.py`, and make it a variable in `myproject/__init__.py` instead:

**`myproject/__init__.py`**:

```
# import foo
# ...

__version__ = '1.5'
```

Import `myproject` in your project's `setup.py`, and replace the hardcoded version with `myproject.__version__`:

**`setup.py`**:

```
from setuptools import setup
from myproject import __version__


project = "myproject"

setup(
    name=project,
    version=__version__,
    # ...
)
```

In your Sphinx project's `conf.py`, do the same. So edit the generated `conf.py` along these lines:

**`docs/conf.py`**:

```
from myproject import __version__

# ...

# The short X.Y version.
version = __version__
# The full version, including alpha/beta/rc tags.
release = version
```

For an example of a library that does this pretty much exactly like this, have a look at the [`requests`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests) module ([`__init__.py`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/__init__.py#L45) | [`setup.py`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/setup.py#L39) | [`conf.py`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/docs/conf.py#L56)).

This will take care of the auto-generated texts where the project version is used (like the links to the front page of the documentation). If you want to use your version in specific custom places, you can use the [`rst_epilog`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030149/how-do-i-output-a-config-value-in-a-sphinx-rst-file/10042061#10042061) directive to dynamically insert configuration values defined in `conf.py`.

Comment: In another SO question it has been pointed out that if you import some dependencies in myproject/__init__.py, and then do `from myproject import __version__` in setup.py, a user won't be able to install the package without installing the dependencies first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058802/how-can-i-get-the-version-defined-in-setup-py-setuptools-in-my-package

Comment: We also had a problem with third-party imports and solved it by introducing a separate package containing only meta information. Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52381178/1600678

Comment: @SeppoEnarvi thank you for the link, it is important to know. However, it seems irrelevant here, because to generate automatic documentation, one has always to import the package (it is different from installing that with *setup.py*).

Answer (score 7):

Maybe an even cleaner option is to actually build sphinx from the `setup.py` command as described in http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/setuptools.html:

setup.py

```
# this is only necessary when not using setuptools/distribute
from sphinx.setup_command import BuildDoc
cmdclass = {'build_sphinx': BuildDoc}

name = 'My project'
version = '1.2'
release = '1.2.0'
setup(
    name=name,
    author='Bernard Montgomery',
    version=release,
    cmdclass=cmdclass,
    # these are optional and override conf.py settings
    command_options={
        'build_sphinx': {
            'project': ('setup.py', name),
            'version': ('setup.py', version),
            'release': ('setup.py', release),
            'source_dir': ('setup.py', 'doc')}},
)
```

Then build documentation using

```
$ python setup.py build_sphinx
```

Benefits:

- Makes `setup.py` the single source of version number
- Avoids having to make packages out of your project folders unnecessarily

Comment: You have to install Sphinx manually for the setup.py to work. So you can't use `pip3 -e .` anymore.

Comment: @Pierre.Sassoulas that's a very good point, thanks for pointing that out. However, this issue may disappear if using `setup.cfg` or a `pyproject.toml`, right? The Sphinx doc has [a section](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/advanced/setuptools.html#using-setuptools-integration) about it.

Comment: From the link you provided: "Deprecated since version 5.0: This feature will be removed in v7.0."

Answer (score 5):

#### Extract Information from pyproject.toml

If you use a `pyproject.toml` you could also parse it in the `conf.py` with [tomli](https://pypi.org/project/tomli/) or use the equivalent [tomllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tomllib.html) when you are on *python ^3.11*.
Like this you can extract the information from the `pyproject.toml` and use it in your sphinx documentation configuration.

Here a short incomplete example using `tomli`, assuming `conf.py`
is located at `<project-root>/docs/source/conf.py`:

```py
# conf.py

import tomli
with open("../../pyproject.toml", "rb") as f:
    toml = tomli.load(f)

# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------

pyproject = toml["tool"]["poetry"]

project = pyproject["name"]
version = pyproject["version"]
release = pyproject["version"]

copyright = ...
author = ...

# and the rest of the configuration
```

Comment: Does not work with dynamic version (`dynamic = ["version"]`) but otherwise a good way to access variables in the `pyproject.toml`.

Answer (score 4):

You could have a look at [`bumpversion`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bumpversion) module:

"A small command line tool to simplify releasing software by updating all version strings in your source code by the correct increment"

You may use a configuration file `.bumpversion.cfg` for complex multi-file operations.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a straightforward solution, ironically from the [setuptools_scm PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools-scm/):

```
# contents of docs/conf.py
from importlib.metadata import version
release = version('myproject')
# for example take major/minor
version = '.'.join(release.split('.')[:2])
```

Here is their explanation why it is discouraged to use their package from Sphinx:

> *The underlying reason is, that services like Read the Docs sometimes change the working directory for good reasons and using the installed metadata prevents using needless volatile data there.*

Answer (score 3):

Another way is integrating `setuptools_scm` in your project. This way you can

```
from setuptools_scm import get_version

version = get_version()
```

in your `conf.py`

Comment: This is the best and most up-to-date answer as of 2022.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [hatchling](https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/) (instead of poetry) variant of [jan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2614160/jan)'s excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75396624/1304076), with a few extra things.

### Getting the version

One extra thing is that it has the source of truth for the version in `my_package/__about__.py`,
so I don't pull it from `pyproject.toml`.

My Sphinx `conf.py` contains something like.

```py
# conf.py
import os
import sys

# ...

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("."))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("../../src"))

from my_package import __about__  # noqa: E402

version = __about__.__version__
```

Note that the `"../../src"` path may be different depending on your project layout.

### Metadata from a hatchling `pyproject.toml`

```py
# conf.py

import tomllib

# ...

# Pull general sphinx project info from pyproject.toml
# Modified from https://stackoverflow.com/a/75396624/1304076
with open("../../pyproject.toml", "rb") as f:
    toml = tomllib.load(f)

pyproject = toml["project"]

project = pyproject["name"]
release = version
author = ",".join(
  [author["name"] for author in pyproject["authors"]]
)
copyright = f"2024 {author}"
```