# How to show version info on index.html page

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am using sphinx and I would like to show the version of my project from conf.py on my main page for documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use 
`:Version: |version|`
in your rst

Comment: it only shows the version you put in the sphinx `conf.py` file, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26141851/let-sphinx-use-version-from-setup-py to know how to do it an automated way

Answer (score 0):

I actually never use Python Sphinx, but I remember seeing a similar question on SO. After searching through, I found the Q+A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030149/how-do-i-output-a-config-value-in-a-sphinx-rst-file)

So you could output the config value directly into your index.rst master doc.

Comment: I tried that but it didnt seem to show on generated HTML page. I am using forked version of read the docs theme. I instead found a different method and much more simpler. I just use `:Version: |version|` in my rst.