# Multiple substitutions with rst_prolog in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, substitution

How do I define multiple global substitutions in Sphinx?

I see [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030149/how-do-i-output-a-config-value-in-a-sphinx-rst-file) how to create global substitutions using `rst_prolog` in conf.py. E.g.,

```
rst_prolog = '.. |my_conf_val| replace:: 42'
```

All examples of this that I can find only define one substitution in `rst_prolog`, but I want to do more than one. I tried this:

```
rst_prolog = """.. |sub1| replace:: mine1\
         .. |sub2| replace:: mine2"""
```

When I put `|sub1|` into text in an rst file, `|sub1|` is (not surprisingly) replaced with:

```
mine1 .. |sub2| replace:: mine2
```

What is the correct syntax here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure that the alignment of the substitution definitions is consistent. Backslashes are not needed. This works:

```
rst_prolog = """
.. |sub1| replace:: mine1
.. |sub2| replace:: mine2
"""
```