# Sphinx documentation variables

Tags: python-sphinx

I'm creating documentation using Sphinx Doc for one of my projects and I'm using many times some words in whole doc, for example - IP address, port numbers and many other things that may change in time. If, for some reason, one of it will be changed, I want to change it simply in one place, not manually in every file. What I'm looking for, is some simple way to create some kind of resource file/variables, which can be easily accessible from all my .rst files.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030149/how-do-i-output-a-config-value-in-a-sphinx-rst-file/10042061#10042061) one:

```
my_config_value = 'test'
rst_epilog = '.. |my_conf_val| replace:: %s' % my_config_value
```

It's almost perfect, but I want to have many variables. Using method above, I'm able to use only one - that's not enough.

Also I have found method using `sphinx.ext.extlinks`. It's working, but not exactly in the way I wanted to. I'm using this in my `conf.py`:

```
extlinks = {'test': ('bla_bla_bla', None)}
```

And then, in some .rst:

```
:test:`1`
```

with result `bla_bla_bla1`

First, this is hyperlink to nowhere. Second, I can't write

```
:test:` `
```

or even just `:test:`, because it doesn't work.

And there come my question: **is there any simple way to create variables, which can be used in whole doc?**

Comment: You can have more than one substitution in `rst_epilog`. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26258989/407651

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thanks to **mzjn** I have found exact answer for my question. If somebody will search for it in future, I left answer below.

In my `conf.py` I added this:

```
address = '192.168.1.1'
port = 'port 3333'

rst_prolog = """
.. |address| replace:: {0}
.. |port| replace:: {1}
""".format(
address, 
port
)
```

And then in my .rst just use:

```
|address| - |port|
```

with result `192.168.1.1 - port 3333`. This is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much **mzjn**.