# How to substitute :target: in image directive in Sphinx?

Tags: image, python-sphinx, substitution, restructuredtext

I have lots of clickable images in my documentation. And most of them have the same base URL.

`base-url = "https://github.com/username/repository/tree/master"`.

In Sphinx, we can add links(`target-url`) to the image as below:

```
.. image:: <image-url>
    :target: <target-url>
```

I want this `target-url` to be substituted by a global variable defined in *conf.py*, so that I can substitute it like:

```
.. image:: <image-url>
    :target: <base-url>/<relative-path>
```

I know that links can be substituted with the help of **sphinx.ext.extlinks** extension. But it is not working for above said purpose. I don't know if this is possible or not. Any alternatives are welcome too.

Answer (score 1):

This question seems related to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227037/substitutions-inside-links-in-rest-sphinx/).

Apparently, even with `extlinks` it is not feasible for image targets, but someone [proposed a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52998585/7262247). Heavy, but might work for you.

Comment: I used the tips shown in that discussion but that didn't work for image targets. However, the other workaround seems promising. I will try it and update it here. Thanks :)